# Facebook real-time updates: not working for some fields

Tags: php, facebook, real-time-updates

Ok, I gave up on posting my bug to Facebook support. It is obvious that they don't read the whole thing. They just read less than half of my question and give me a quick answer so that they can close the ticket.

My MAIN problem with Facebook's real time update is that I cannot subscribe to the **fields political, favorite_athletes, favorite_teams and significant_other**. Do you guys have the same problem? If you do, can you please report the bug for me because I have given up.

Again, my problem is s that I cannot subscribe to the **fields political, favorite_athletes, favorite_teams and significant_other**. The following is what I wrote to Facebook:

This is a continuation to the other bug that I reported about real-time updates. It was stated that I could not do it for connections like groups, but I was able to do it for movie, television and couple of other ones.

I also get errors for the fields **political, favorite_athletes, favorite_teams and significant_other**

Repro

### Steps to Reproduce: Entered the following addresses and got these errors:

https://graph.facebook.com/***/subscriptions?access_token=***&object=user&fields=political&verify_token=***&method=post&callback_url=***

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) \"political\" is an invalid field name",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

---

https://graph.facebook.com/***/subscriptions?access_token=***&object=user&fields=favorite_athletes&verify_token=***&method=post&callback_url=***

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "(#100) \"favorite_athletes\" is an invalid field name",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100
    }
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it's possible as of right now.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

> This object supports Real-Time Updates for the following connections: feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies, television, likes, checkins.

Comment: what about the **FIELDS** (not connections) political, favorite_athletes, favorite_teams and significant_other? I was able to subscribe to a lot of other fiels (e.g. religion), but I could not do it for those.

Comment: You're right, I'm having the same issue. I'll submit a bug report too.